# rasterlite build issues

Tags: spatialite, rasterlite

i am able to build rasterlite library but when it is building .exe for tools(rasterlite_load) it gives linking error for external symbole *SPLite3*
like this
rasterlite_load.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SPLite3_last_in
sert_rowid referenced in function _export_tile
there are many like this but all are due to splite

I don't know what is missing. Searching google gives sqlite reference.

Development Environment - windows and vc
libraster version -1.1c

Thanks